# Retrieve file size from web server

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Looking for a way to retrieve a file size from a web server using cocoa/foundation. I know one can use NSURLconnection which will return NSURLResponse that contains the file size. Is there any other way to get the size. I'm looking for a synchronous way of doing it so when i do [myClass getsize] the size is returned.

Thanks

Comment: Note that doing it synchronously will make your app unusable until the response comes back, which could be X minutes from now or never at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`NSMutableURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableURLRequest) to send a HTTP HEAD request (there’s a method called `setHTTPMethod`). You’ll get the same response headers as with GET, but you won’t have to download the whole resource body. And if you want to get the data synchronously, use the [`sendSynchronousRequest…`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:) method of `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: @zoul: Indeed that works. Thanks for your help. Here is what i did:

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
requestWithURL:aURL
        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
        timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];